# How to Export Viewport3D to a 2d Image file?

Tags: wpf, 3d, screenshot

I'm using 3d in WPF and want to save it to a 2d image file, kind of screen shot.
What's the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his [12 days of WPF 3D](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/index.html) series, Eric Sink has a nice post about [Rendering a WPF 3D scene to a Bitmap](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/3_Bitmap.html). Also of interest might be the post on [Printing](http://www.ericsink.com/wpf3d/B_Printing.html) support.

And for any WPF 3D user, I highly recommend the (open-source) [Helix 3D Toolkit](http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com), which has several importers and exporters to different formats, and is an essential WPF 3D companion library.